# Woocommerce + oceanwp banner configuration in function.php

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, banner

So my plan was to add custom banner to all pages simply using code in functions.php, it works, but not how I would like to

Code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'after_main_content', 1 );

function after_main_content() {
    echo  ' <style>
      .img-container {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
 <div class="img-container">
<img src="https://www.prospecs.lt/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/dpdtt-1.png" >
  </div>
';
}
```

Problem:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zBux.png]

Only in pages with sidebars my banner get's allocated to another section.
[image]
Any ideas how to place it in the right place on pages with sidebar?

my site: [www.prospecs.lt](http://www.prospecs.lt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, you should use a theme footer action. Which is: ocean_after_main So the code would be:

```
   add_action( 'ocean_after_main', 'after_main_content', 1 );
                function after_main_content() {
            if( is_shop() ){
                    echo  ' <style>
                      .img-container {
                        text-align: center;
                      }
                    </style>
                 <div class="img-container">
                <img src="https://www.prospecs.lt/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/dpdtt-1.png" >
                  </div>
                ';
            }
    }
```